# Different implementation of Feynman's clock

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-computer

In equation 7 of the paper, [Feynman's clock, a new variational principle, and parallel-in-time quantum dynamics](http://arxiv.org/abs/1301.2326), the clock register is different from Feynman's [original proposal](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall05/frs119/papers/feynman85_optics_letters.pdf). According to this paper, for a four clock steps quantum circuit, the sequence of the state of the clock register will be $|00\rangle \to |01\rangle \to |10\rangle \to |11\rangle$. It infers that we will need a two qubit register. But according to Feynman's original proposal, it should be $|000\rangle \to |100\rangle \to |010\rangle \to |001\rangle$ i.e. a three qubit clock register is needed.

I failed to understand if there is any specific reason behind this modification. Any help?